# Wordpress: Restoring a theme to it's default settings

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, drop-table

So I installed the "twenty fourteen" theme for my Wordpress website, and I want to change it to it's deault settings. With this I mean resetting the theme to how it was when first installed (with no modifications).

Currently I have checked the database to check if I could restore the wp-options theme value to default, but that item on the database does not exist. I also tried changing themes, deleting twenty "fourteen" and installing again from wordpress and still no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you enter some content in it that you want to keep?

If it's the case, what you can do is:

1. Export all your content (left admin menu > Tools > Export).
2. Install [**WordPress Reset** plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-reset/) and activate it. Then go to Tools > WordPress Reset. Then type 'reset' in the text field and click reset.
3. Import all your content (left admin menu > Tools > Import)

You can uninstall **WordPress Reset** plugin. Thats all.